# Displaying entries from fire base whose dates have not passed

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic3, angularfire2

I am working on an app where a user can book on certain dates, after booking I want the user to be able to view his appointments but only the ones whose dates haven't passed yet.

I have tried comparing the date of the retrieved record with the a date value that I created that has the latest date but had no luck.

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let a of Appointments|async">
    <ng-container *ngIf="id == a.UID && a.Date.Day &ge; d">
      <ion-item >
        <ion-label> {{a.Date.Day}} </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

Typescript

```
 id;       //Stores ID of logged in user.
  users;   //Stores list of all users.
  Appointments;
  date;
  d;
  constructor(public afAuth:AngularFireAuth, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public firebase: FirebaseProvider) {
    afAuth.authState.subscribe( user => {
      if (user) { this.id = user.uid }
    });
    this.Appointments = this.firebase.getBookedAppointments();
    this.date = new Date();
    this.d = moment(this.date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
  }
```

I tested the value of the data being retrieved from firebase and I can view and output the value just fine. However when I include the condition:-

```
a.Date.Day &ge; d
```

I get this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckWCX.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Typescript/Javascript you cannot use the ≥ sign, which is what you're trying to do in your code. If you look at the error you've posted it says 'Unexpected character [≥]'.

The correct operator for 'greater than or equals' is `>=`. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Greater_than_or_equal_operator).